# Supreme in proof of Archimedes axiom is natural number?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Proof of Archimedes axiom is written following way in my textbook.

**Archimedes axiom** : $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above.

**proof** : Suppose $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded above. Since $\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ is not empty, there exists supreme.

Let $\alpha$ := sup $\mathbb{N}$.

Since $\alpha-1<\alpha$, we can take a $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha-1<m$. Thus $\alpha<m+1$.

However, $m+1 \in \mathbb{N}$ , thus $m+1 \leq \alpha$. This is contradiction. $\Box$

I have a question $\alpha$ is natural namber ?

Please explain me whether $\alpha$ is natural namber or not.

Comment: $\alpha$ is not necessarily natural.

Comment: @koro Why? Please tell me more.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are using the least upper bound property of the reals, $\alpha$ is assumed to be a real number. At least under the assumption that $\mathbb N$ is bounded above.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha$ is not necessarily a natural number, but can be one. A priori it is just the smallest real number, which is larger or equal than every natural number.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that the naturals have an upper bound, $α$ is defined as the supremum of the naturals. The supremum axiom does not say anything about what $α$ is, but guarantees that any smaller real number is not an upper bound on the naturals. That is why your textbook notes that $α-1 < α$, so $α-1$ is not an upper bound and hence is less than some natural $m$.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have already understood this proof. But, in this situation, I guess α is natural intuitively...

Comment: @Nikolai: Well... it's not quite right to say anything about α because it was defined only under the (actually false) assumption that the naturals have an upper bound! It is just like saying, if there is a biggest prime number $p$, then it is less than $10$. Sure it is.